# How to retain attributes in Feature to Polygon tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I have a polygon of Karaikal city which I split into different sections using Feature to Polygon tool.
Below shown is the table of Karaikal polygon before split

[image]

After splitting into different sections using feature to polygon tool the kml_name field is blank. Refer image below.

[image]

Is there any way how I can preserve the values in kml_name field?

Or Do I have to update that column after splitting? If yes, then how?

Comment: After split, use spatial join to carry out polygon attributes to the splitted polygons.

Answer (score 2):

Right click the Field Name which is in your case [kml_name] go to Field Calculator and write "Karaikal". The double quotation mark is must, and it will update all your cells at once.

Based on [Feature To Polygon tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/feature-to-polygon.htm), there is an option to preserve the attribute. you need to check that. If it is unchecked, the attribute will not be preserved. I think you need to provide label feature (point). The help says:

> If the Preserve attributes option on the dialog box is checked (the attributes parameter is set to ATTRIBUTES in scripting), the output attributes schema and field values will **depend on whether the label features (points) are provided** in the following ways:

You can continue reading the details from the above link. But I want to emphasize that label points are necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Ahmadhanb. This is an example of 1 city. I have more than 500 cities to be split in this way in one go. After splitting I won't be able to update the column using field calculator.

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: I tried that just now. Gives the same output.

Comment: I updated my answer again.