# Feature to Polygon in ArcGIS Pro: attribute missing although Preserve attributes is checked and feature labels are provided

Tags: arcgis-pro, labeling, fields-attributes, polygon-creation, feature-class

I try to follow the suggestion given in an [equal case](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199413/how-to-retain-attributes-in-feature-to-polygon-tool) in ArcGIS Desktop, however, I do not end up with the desired result. I start with the Shapefile Feature Class `lgm_3_contour_edit.shp` of Geometry Type Line. It contains the attribute `Contour` which is provided as a label (right-click on layer in `Contents` > `Labeling Properties ...`) and used to label the lines in the Map. Polygons are generated from these lines with the tool `Feature to Polygon` whereas the attribute should be retained. However, the attribute is not retained.

Is there a misunderstanding about the handling of labels, is there an error in my usage of of the tool, or has the tool's functionality changed from ArcGIS Desktop?

I'm using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.2 on Windows 11 Pro 22H2.

[image: Missing attribute for polygon]

Comment: Preserve attributes are intended for isolated polygons, in the case of contours there is potentially two bounding values: going up and going down, which of these would you keep? What you're trying to create is known as *hypsometric areas* and it's a lot more difficult than it seems.

Comment: The comment makes sense, however, I thought the meaning of contours would not matter in this process. Technically, the attribute "Contour" is just an attribute like "Parcel Border" or "Lakeshore" with a certain value, i. e. ArcGIS should ot care about the value being a bounding value between two adjacent areas. Furthermore, each polygon created by this process is an isolated polygon regardless whether they enclose each other or not - aren't they? Maybe the chosen tool is not appropriate for my attempt.

Comment: The doc states "*It is recommended that you do not use the Preserve attributes parameter, as it is no longer supported and does not work. It will remain, however, for backward compatibility of scripts and models.*". Also, the label parameter is referring to a point featureclass or layer that contains attributes to transfer to the polygon, not the labels of the line.

Comment: The issue here is the logical assignment of elevation infills. Each polygon may have 2 contour values (normal) or one contour value (isolations); in the case of an isolation you need to determine if the isolation is going up (most common) or going down (re-entrant on edge of data or depression) and then assign a value to the polygon *one contour interval higher or lower*; you can't have the same polygon value on *both* sides of the contour. If you have a raster that your contours were generated from you could use a tool like reclassify or slice to  create hypsometric bands.